# App start breaks, when Mobile Quality Assurance Cordova Plugin?

Tags: cordova, ibm-cloud, hybrid, ibm-mobile-services, mobilefirst-qa

My MFP Cordova Ionic Hybrid Andriod App Breaks, 
when MQA Session starts. (Using MQA Bluemix)

Who has the same behavior?

I do not use the doDeviceReady function, because is not needed for the app.
I tried it first but is not fired in my app, so the mfp Cordova integration like written in [Installing the Mobile Quality Assurance plug-in for Apache Cordova](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/t_download_cordova_plugin.html)
not needed.

I use my Android Nexus 9 for running the hybrid application.
Android 5.0.1 Kernel-Version 3.10.40-ga3846f1

Difference:

a) I changed the MQA session code a bit and I used the MQA Session Start in wlCommonInit() in index.js.
I tried to run it on a real anroid device.

```
MQA.startNewSession(
{ // Options
      mode: "QA", // or mode: "MARKET" for production mode.
      android: {
                 appKey: "XXX" ,
                 notificationsEnabled: false
                },
      ios:     {
                 appKey: "XXX" ,
                 screenShotsFromGallery: false,
               },
      //serverURL: "https://devops.quality4mobile.com" , // The default value is the IBM Bluemix server.
      //defaultUser: "email_address", // The mail address of the tester so it does not have to be repepeatedly entered.
      machExceptionEnabled: false, // Ensure debugging mode is not on when this
                                   //  value is set to true.
      reportOnShakeEnabled: true  // Enable problem reporting with a shake.
 }, successMQA, errorMQA);

 function successMQA() {
 console.log("MQA Session Started successfully");
 }

 function errorMQA(error) {
  console.log("MQA Session error" + error);
 }
```

I do not have the ability to provide additional debugging or log because it breaks directly, before the "chrome inspect device" can show any interaction.

I followed mostly the instruction here:

MQA Cordova Integration:
[Installing the Mobile Quality Assurance plug-in for Apache Cordova](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/t_download_cordova_plugin.html)

Verified information here:
MFP Integration with Cordova:
[Integrating IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation SDK in Cordova applications](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/)

Comment: Are you running Marshmallow on your Android device?

Comment: Try using this code just to see if it works:

Comment: MQA.startNewSession({
         mode: "QA",
         android: {
            appKey: "your app key here" ,
            notificationsEnabled: true
           },
         ios: {
            appKey: "your app key here" ,
            screenShotsFromGallery: true,
              }
       },
          {
         success: function () {console.log("Session Started successfully");},
         error: function (string) { console.log("Session error" + string);}
       });

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks for your Feedback. 

This code is the code from the help, I tried first. I know it is better to switch of the Photo Library. The Answer is this code is already tested. I already put the links to the Help and Guide in Question.

Comment: Does the code I provide work? I'm just trying to narrow down where the problem may be. Thanks

Comment: No, the code does not work. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the MFP project working by including the MQA.startNewSession in the wlCommonInit function.

Comment: Yes, thanks is works :-).

Download the latest cordova sdk : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27044490

Comment: If you want to check the sample code by yourself just take look here: https://github.com/thomassuedbroecker/TempTracker_IoTBluemixMFPSample#4211-optional-add-mqa-to-bluemix-application-and-configure-mobileapp